# Draw a time series plot using r

Tags: r, plot, time

I am attempting to draw a time series plot using r.  My data look like this:

```
A tibble: 96 x 2
   interval average_received
     <fctr>            <dbl>
 1     0:00         3.034483
 2     0:30         2.300000
 3     0:45         2.473684
 4     1:30         1.647059
 5    10:00        18.161290
 6    10:15        16.096774
 7    10:30        18.064516
 8    10:45        15.677419
 9    11:00        15.709677
```

R is reading in `interval` as a factor.  I want it to be a time object in `minutes:seconds`, then plot it on the x-axis, with average_received on the y-axis.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. We can add a date to the `interval` column and then convert the column to `POSIXct` class. The date will not be shown in the later plot so it could be any dates, which just helps the type conversion. We can then use `ggplot2` to plot the data and specify the format on the x-axis.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(interval = ymd_hm(paste("2018-05-12", interval, sep = " ")))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = interval, y = average_received)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   interval average_received
                  1     0:00         3.034483
                  2     0:30         2.300000
                  3     0:45         2.473684
                  4     1:30         1.647059
                  5    10:00        18.161290
                  6    10:15        16.096774
                  7    10:30        18.064516
                  8    10:45        15.677419
                  9    11:00        15.709677",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH.  The plot with all my data was fantastic!

Comment: Glad to help. If my post solved your question, please consider to accept this post as the answer.

Comment: I'd like to accept this post as the answer.  How do I do this?

Comment: @MayRobinson Please see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work to learn how to accept an answer.